# When do I see updates on hibernate entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Let's say I'm using spring and hibernate and I do something like the following in one of my transactional service methods. What would be the expected outcomes of the prints and more importantly why?

```
// user1 perviously has some other name then x
User userInstance = userDAO.findById(1);
userInstance.setName("x");
System.out.println(userDAO.findById(1).getName());

userDAO.save(userInstance);
System.out.println(userDAO.findById(1).getName());
```

Would I always expect to see the changes that I made to the user entity I queried and why? How exactly does this interact with the hibernate proxy and the first level cache?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the same session, Hibernate will use the first level cache to ensure that the same entity (identified by the same primary key) is always represented by the same object instance.
This means that until you close the session, whether you interact with the referenced entity `userInstance` or you do it trough Hibernate with `userDAO.findById(1)` you will always be referring to the exact same object instance.

So to answer your question, the printed result would be:
x
x

Comment: Is that really the case? I always thought hibernate caches the data for sure but I wasn't aware that it actually also always refers to the same object instances underneath.

Comment: Within the same session yes, we are always referring to the same persistent context store until we flush or commit the transaction. That will make the session look for any dirty entity and sync them to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that line 2 should have used `userInstance` instead of `userInstance1`.  I think you will see an update flushed to the database when line 3 (below) is executed:

```
System.out.println(userDAO.findById(1).getName());
```

The reason is that you have an unsaved but updated the version in memory so it is considered "dirty".  When you re-read that same object (based on the ID), hibernate will flush the updated object first to the database before re-reading it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! But as I mentioned in the question this will be inside an @transactional method. That would mean to me that no db statements will be executed until the method has returned and the transaction is commited or am I wrong there?